# Most of his early years was or were?

Tags: tense

If we use "is" after "30 years" then what should i use after "most of his early years", "was" or "were"??

Comment: Ignore the word ***most***. What matters is that the "head" noun is plural ***years*** - so the verb form should be plural ***were***, not singular ***was***. We only use ***is*** after ***years*** in contexts like ***30 years is** a long time*, where "30 years" collectively is being treated as a "single" *duration* of time (as with ***Ten million pounds is** a lot of money* and similar). We don't do that with *His early years **was** difficult* - that has to be *His early years **were** difficult*.

Answer (score 1):

The subject here is "years", and since it is plural, we have to use plural form "were".

"Was" is used for singular e.g. "year"

> This year was a pain

We only use "is" after years in contexts like 30 years is a long time, where "30 years" collectively is being treated as a "single" duration of time (as with *Ten million pounds* **is** a lot of money and similar) - @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 0):

The pronoun "most" can be singular or plural. Generally, when we say "most of [object]", the pronoun takes the same number as the object. For example:

> Most of the dogs are brown.
> Most of the water is salty.

However, in certain contexts it is possible to construe "most" otherwise. For example:

> Most of the oats have fallen onto the floor.
> Most of the oats has fallen onto the floor.

The first sentence treats "the oats" as many individual items, while the second treats it as a single object.

Now let's consider your construction:

> Most of his early years were filled with joy.
> Most of his early years was filled with joy.

The first sentence treats "the years" as individual items, while the second treats it as a single length of time.

Keep in mind that this is only one approach to indefinite pronouns. Some people would have no problem with using plural "most" for a single item.